# NetCDF projection conversion to EPSG3857 is cropped in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mapbox, netcdf

I am using QGIS and PyQGIS to transform NetCDF files projection to EPSG:3857. My ultimate goal is export it as raster (TIFF or PNG) to display in Mapbox.

When first imported, the NetCDF file itself does not have a projection so I set the layer's CRS to EPSG4326 while the project CRS is EPSG:3857. It seems to have converted correctly, however, when a world shape file is overlaid, the north above Greenland is cropped. I understand that the because EPSG:3857 projection outputs a square, the latitude only goes from -85 to 85.

Is there a way to manually configure so it outputs correctly like the second image? (produced from Panoply).

[image: screenshot from QGIS]

[image: screenshot of Panoply]